# How to establish connection between rails 4 app with oracle database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oracle11g

Specifications: 
               ruby 2.0.0
               Rails 4
               Oracle 11g
How to establish connection between rails 4 app with oracle database with above specifications

Comment: see this:http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/saternos-ror-faq-097353.html#3

Comment: And this will help too:http://www.pixellatedvisions.com/2009/03/26/rails-on-oracle-part-2-setting-up-rails-to-connect-to-an-oracle-database

Comment: Check this link below it will help you out.
http://railsengine.blogspot.in/2013/09/oracle-with-rails-riding-rails-on-oracle.html